# Heatmaps with local maxima, weight, API functionalities

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, google-maps, heat-map

I am looking for a heatmap vizualization on a map, which shows:

1. local maxima: that means that you always see some "red spots" regardless the zoom. See the picture below.

[image]

2. enables to set a weight to the points.
3. provides an API.

Ideally I would like to also display a legend for the heatmap.

**UPDATE**
Based on my research and a comment of @IvanSanchez I found that:

[image]

Leaflet with leaflet.heat plugin and heatmap.js turned out to cover all three requirements. However, a problem with heatmap.js was that points being plotted are very close to each other and the outcome was a red overlay rather than a heatmap. See the picture below. This problem was overcome in leaflet by setting *radius* and a *blur* parameters. Leaflet turned out to be the best option.

[image]

Comment: According to the [readme for Leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat), the data points must be given in `[lat, lng, intensity]` format, so your claim that Leaflet.heat does not allow to set weights of individual data points is incorrect.

Comment: I completely overlooked that. I will check and let you know. Thank you for response!

Comment: Please remember to edit and update your question with your new findings!